# Py Click (8.0) flag_value gets converted to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I've been using `click` for a while now and it has worked perfectly
fine. Today I upgraded to version 8.0.1 and noticed that when one uses an option with a `flag_value` set to a class instead of an instance,
the `flag_value` gets converted to a string representation:

```py
import click

@click.command()
@click.option("--yes", flag_value=int)
def test(yes):
    print("yes=", yes, "type(yes)=", type(yes))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

```sh
$ test.py --yes
yes= <class 'int'> type(yes)= <class 'str'>
```

Is this behavior intended? If so, why? I couldn't find anything related to the behaviour of flags in the change log.

This obviously break backwards-compatibility. Before switching to click 8.0 it returned the object just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was changed with [this PR](https://github.com/pallets/click/commit/e79c2b47aa5b456e6c70f980ecf0f883447eb340#diff-dcb534e6a7591b92836537d4655ddbd2f18e3b293c3420144c30a9ca08f65c4eR184).

It appears the intent, is that since the default type of the parameter is a string, it would be good to return one.  It was released with a [Major Semver](https://semver.org/) change at 8.0, so there was some warning of potential breaking changes.

You can emulate the prior behavior like this:

```py
import click

class StringOrTypeParamType(click.types.StringParamType):

    def convert(self, value, param, ctx):
        if isinstance(value, type):
            return value
        else:
            return super().convert(value, param, ctx)

@click.command()
@click.option("--yes", flag_value=int, type=StringOrTypeParamType())
def test(yes):
    print("yes=", yes, "type(yes)=", type(yes))
```